# Command-line input

Tags: python, loops, command-line-arguments

I need to write a complete program that obtains three pieces of data and then process them. The three pieces of information are a Boolean value, a string, and an integer. The logic of the program is this: if the Boolean value is True, print out the string twice, once with double quotes and once without - otherwise print out twice the number. Which I can do just fine, but then I have to write the same program but this time using command-line input, the program below is what I have so far but i keep getting a command not found error.I feel like my "for i in range" is the error

```
 import sys

 def main():
     x = sys.argv[0].lower() == 'true'
     y = str(sys.argv[1])
     z = int(sys.argv[2])
     for i in range(0,len(sys.argv),1):
        print("   ",i,":",sys.argv[i])
     return 0;
```

Comment: How are you executing your program? It seems like it might be a shell error.

Comment: Please include the exact error you are seeing.  "command not found" sounds more to me like you aren't calling you Python program correctly, so it might be unrelated to the code.  As for the code, `sys.argv[0]` is the name of the script so you should start at `sys.argv[1]` to get any arguments passed to the script.

Comment: @PlasmaPower no ... the first of argv is never your first argument ...

Comment: Are you executing your script like this: `python my_script.py` ? Or just like `./my_script.py` ?

Comment: I execute it using python3 command.py

Comment: if you just execute "python3" do you get a python command prompt?

Comment: Also your code does nothing but define a function called main (so exits without actually doing anything) -- unrelated to the "not found" error though

Comment: Thats probably why I dont get a command prompt since all it does is define the function "main"

Answer (score 1):

"Command not found" is the shell response when a file is not in the $PATH or it was never made executable. First make sure that it is executable with

```
chmod +x myfile.py
```

second make sure that it is in your path with

```
which myfile.py
```

If it is not in your path, you need to execute it with an explicit path such as './myfile.py'

If it is not executable and you do not change it to executable you need to use

```
python [full path or .]/myfile.py
```

In your comment, you say that you execute it with "python3" doublecheck that it is the correct call for your system.

I almost forgot to add that the first line in your script needs to be

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

or whatever python points to in your system

Answer (score 0):

```
def main():
     x = sys.argv[1].lower() == 'true'
     y = str(sys.argv[2])
     z = int(sys.argv[3])
     if x:
         print "'{}'".format(y)
         print '"{}"'.format(y)
     else:
         print 2*z
     return 0;
if __name__ == '__main__':
     main()
```

save this as myfile.py
then from the shell run: `chmod +x myfile.py  && python myfile.py`

Comment: Once he makes it executable he should not need to run it with python thoug he should put in the #! line first

Comment: but it shows my x = sys.argv[1] to be out of range which i would assume would make all 3 x,y,z values out of range

Comment: depending on whether you run "python myfile.py" or just ./myfile.py then args will be shifted by 1